# Angular sharing data between two components

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to share  a value from one service to another componet but the value result is showing as undefined

```
Injectable()
export class TestService {
 url:string;

someExample(){
this.url="Hello";
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  constructor(private test: TestService,
              ) { }

  doTest(){    
   console.log("CheckingValue"+ this.test.url)
  }
}
```

How do I set url value so that I can receive on another component? I am new to angular
I can see in console this.test.url values is showing as  undefined

Answer (score 0):

you are calling a variable by just defining it so it's by default **`undefined`**, so call a method which added a value to it.

just add **`return`** in your **someExample()** method

```
someExample() {
   return  this.url="Hello";
}
```

> **Example.component.ts**

```
doTest() {    
  console.log("CheckingValue"+ this.test.someExample())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Observable to subscribe for changes:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

Injectable()
export class TestService {
 url:string;

someExample(): Observable<string>{
 return of (this.url="Hello");
}
```

And get/ subscribe for it in the component:

```
this.testService.someExample().subscribe(result => {
 console.log(result);
});
```

If the value changes in the service, you will get the updated value in the component.

Comment: someexample() { 

    
    
    return Observable.create(observer => {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
    
    //Some data processing
    
    
    this.url="Hai";
    
    
    }});
    
    
    
   getExample(){
   
   return this.url;
   
   }
   
   
   On the other component I am getting this value as undefined
   How do I store this.url value within Observable

Comment: I am not sure about your exact user case, but looks like you are looking for https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc

Comment: Could you please elaborate the user case? What exactly you are trying to do with the shared service.

Comment: Within the observable part of the code,I am trying to extract an url value and storing it on this.url variable. This url variable I am passing as a return value on one of the function.So that i can retrieved this url value in other components but I am getting the value as undefined.If I I am doing the same process without observable I am getting the url value in other components.Dont know why with observable the value of this.url variable is not storing as a global variable.